# ansible set_fact if-else failure

Tags: if-statement, ansible

I am trying to set_fact value based on condition with if-else ,Below is syntax which I use for the if-else condition .

```
- name: set the server details
  set_fact:
    ad_server: "{{ '{{ server.westeurope }}' if ('{{ ansible_local.vdc.location }}' == 'westeurope') else '{{ server.eastus2 }}' }}"
    ad_server_ip: "{% if'{{ ansible_local.vdc.location }}'=='westeurope' %}{{ server_ip.westeurope }}{% else %}{{ server_ip.eastus2 }}{% endif %}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_local.vdc.location }},{{ ansible_local.vdc.binaryrepo_url }},{{ ad_server }},{{ ad_server_ip }}"
```

I have already declared my variable section with the details as mentioned below :

```
server:
  westeurope: WIN030123
  eastus2: WIN100270
server_ip:
  westeurope: 10.x.x.x
  eastus2: 10.x.x.x
```

my if-else condition fails to get the value of if statement and always gets the value of else condition ..Can someone provide me the correct syntax for this situation.

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: I have updated in correct format

Answer (score 5):

Using Jinja2 there are different types of markup to define logic and variable expansion and : [more information on the Jinja2 Ansible page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/container_yml/template.html).

So if you want to do logic (branching) and variable expansion on the same line, like on you first fact setting that will be :

```
    ad_server: "{% if ansible_local.vdc.location == 'westeurope' %}{{ server.westeurope }}{% else %}{{ server.eastus2 }}{% endif %}"
```

Please try it.

Comment: Great!. How can we do this in multiple lines?

Answer (score 3):

Use Jinja2 [if expression](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#if-expression):

```
- name: set the server details
  set_fact:
    ad_server: "{{ server.westeurope if ansible_local.vdc.location == 'westeurope' else server.eastus2 }}"
    ad_server_ip: "{{ server_ip.westeurope if ansible_local.vdc.location == 'westeurope' else server_ip.eastus2 }}"
```

Comment: Thanks @konstantin ..that really worked ..I was making it complex .

Comment: Great!. this also worked for me. What's the difference between this and answer provided by Bathz? Which method is preferred..?